# How convert dd/mm/yyy to date using javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

How do I convert the value 24/05/2016 (`typeof(24/05/2016)` is number) for a `Date` using JavaScript?

> While performing the following error occurs:

**transactionDateAsString.split is not a function"**

```js
var transactionDateAsString = 24/05/2015;
var parts = transactionDateAsString.split("/");
var dudu = parts + '';
var date = new Date(dudu[2], dudu[1] - 1, dudu[0]);
console.log(date);
```

Comment: what???????????

Comment: How can type of 24/05/2016 be a number?

Comment: That's not a string anymore, that's a number (`0.002382134`) No way to get the original terms back.

Comment: but the database returns me exactly 24/05/2016

Comment: @durtto — What does that have to do with it?

Comment: but the database returns me exactly 24/05/2016

Comment: The database returns you a String (or maybe a Date), not a number. If you want to put that into Javascript, put quotes around it (as in @this.lau_'s answer).

Comment: @Thilo the database return number

Comment: how to convert 24.05.2016 to '24 / 05/2016 ' @Quentin

Comment: 24/05/2016 is not a number. Maybe a non-sensical term that can be evaluated arithmetically to a number. But not a number.

Comment: @Thilo — The result of evaluating a number divided by a number divided by a number will always be a number in JS

Comment: @durtto — Where did 24.05.2016 come from?

Comment: MSSQL @Quentin ..

Comment: @durtto — I meant "Why are you asking about 24.05.2016 now? There's no sign of it in the question. You don't appear to have solved the problem in your question."

Comment: @Quentin: That is what I am saying. `24/05/2016` is a snippet of Javascript that can be evaluated to a number. But it is not a valid number literal itself. And a database returning `24/05/2016` or `24.05.2016` is not returning a number.

Comment: When date will be string you still will not have the current date bacause `dudu` will be string `'24,05,2015'`

Comment: I mean that is returning it, do not you understand? You should help me handle the situation to invez to make decisions for me. How do I turn this blessed 24/05/2016 in date?

Comment: @durtto — You can't. All you have is `0.0023809523809523807`. You need to put something useful as the input to the script instead of those three numbers and two division operators.

Comment: but what I have is this. How to convert?

Comment: What's wrong with the @this.lau_ answer?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why you are adding an empty string at some point. This is how it should be:

```
var transactionDateAsString = '24/05/2015';
var parts = transactionDateAsString.split("/");
var date = new Date(parts[2],parts[1]-1,parts[0]);
alert(date);
```

Also note the quotes around the date as string.

Comment: but the database returns me exactly 24/05/2016

Comment: Please post your exact code then. Or do you mean you're getting a Unix timestamp?

Comment: how to convert 24.05.2016 to '24 / 05/2016 '

Comment: "24.05.2016".split(".").join("/")  But why convert?